# magento disable product listing in top category

Tags: php, mysql, html, xml, magento

I need to disable to product listing in Magento ( 1.4 ) Top Categories, any idea or tip how can I best achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to *Catalog > Manage Categories > Display Settings* then for the categories you wish set the *Display Mode* to *Static block only*. You can see this being done on the [Magento demo store](http://demo-admin.magentocommerce.com/), look at "[Electronics](http://demo.magentocommerce.com/electronics)" category.